Data annotations not recognized by Entity Framework Core in one ASP.NET project but work properly in another
I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1 with a "code-first" approach for 2 ASP.NET projects on .NET 4.8. "Code first" is in quotes because this is really a migration from EF 6 where we've deleted the .edmx file and revised the DbContext. The database schema is locked and we are only looking to get this functioning, not allow it to adapt to new db changes (and re-generating the DbContext/entities is not an option because it breaks an unbelievable amount of code).
Anyways - I have one web project working great (as well as several console projects and windows services), but the last ASP.NET Web API project keeps throwing errors, at first when initializing the DbContext and then when running queries.
All of the exceptions are due to the fact that the entity class data annotations are not being recognized.
Here's an example of an entity which includes all the attributes that are in use:
namespace Model.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;    
    
    [Table("FaxStatus", Schema = "Global")]
    public partial class FaxStatus
    {
        [Key]
        public int FaxId { get; set; }
        public string XMLStatus { get; set; }
        public string XMLStatusMessage { get; set; }
        public string XMLPath { get; set; }
    }
}

The attributes define the table, schema, and key for this entity.
Again, this works fine in half a dozen other projects. In the problem project, at DbContext initialization I got an error that there was no key defined and had to add an OnModelCreating HasKey entry to make it happy (this is only for keys that don't follow convention of course).
Then, when I had added all those entries, making a query like this:
using (var db = new EFContext())
{
    var statuses = db.FaxStatuses.FirstOrDefault();
}

This code throws the error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'FaxStatuses'

I even checked the SQL Server Profiler -- it's trying to use the DbSet<FaxStatus> property name (FaxStatuses) as the table name instead of one specified in the attribute (or even the class name).
In other words, the SQL should be:
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Global.FaxStatus

But instead, it is:
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Global.FaxStatuses

I've verified that all the EF Core libraries (base, SqlServer, Relational, Proxies, Abstractions) are installed in the project with the same versions as the working project. I've looked in all the application startup code and can't find anything related to EF Core configuration that might mess things up.
And the DbContext and entity classes are in a shared library used by all of these different projects.
Why is this one Web API project ignoring the attributes on these classes?
Edit: A couple people have asked about FaxStatuses; it is declared in my DBContext class like so:
public DbSet<FaxStatus> FaxStatuses { get; set; }

I also have a reference to it in OnModelCreating:
modelBuilder.Entity<FaxStatus>();


Maybe a stupid suggestion, but did you check if db.FaxStatuses actually refers to a DbSet of that same FaxStatus class?

@GertArnold Fair question! But yes.

there is no "FaxStatuses" (SQL object) in shown code.
i would try
1- search for "FaxStatuses" in project/solution ,
2 - enable ef net core logging to find what query results in such error

it using pluralization tables, turn off the pluralization of table names in Entity Framework Core and check

@ish1313 I have added the relevant DBContext code at the end. I mentioned the issue with the query in my question but I have updated it to provide the specific SQL query causing the issue.

@Thirupathicst I believe that applies to creating databases; once it is already created, the table name should be the class name, and can be overwritten by the TableAttribute. Is that incorrect? I'm also at a loss for why this would cause the code to work different between two WebApi projects.

@Daniel can you try this [Table("FaxStatus"] instead of [Table("FaxStatus", Schema = "Global")], and run add-migration command, if migration works fine then naming issue can be solved.

@Daniel, i would try to rename faxstatuses here "public DbSet FaxStatuses { get; set; }" to something other . say tblFaxStatuses to check will object in exception changes.   "modelBuilder.Entity();" that's reference to class, not to table or dbset.   i would try to delete /obj & /bin , clean project , restart vs and rebuild

@Daniel "And the DbContext and entity classes are in a shared library used by all of these different projects." - if dbcontext is shared with the working project try to use the same code from the working project. it it works, the problem is in new project configuration .

Have you tried modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("FaxStatus"); According to EF Core on Microsoft's website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0#create-the-database-context, An entity set typically corresponds to a database table AND An entity corresponds to a row in the table.

Have you tried removing this code modelBuilder.Entity<FaxStatus>(); from the OnModelCreating method ? Having the DbSet in the context should be enough and you may be adding the same table twice to your model

The resolution ended up being downgrading System.ComponentModel.Annotations from 5.0.0 to 4.7.0 in the problematic WebAPI project. All the attributes were recognized immediately.
